# How to Delete files in Linux with to the date in the file name?

Tags: linux, logging, delete-file

I have a folder as /var/test/logs in my Linux VM server. It has folders as below (sample):

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 01 00:00 Backuplogs_202212010000
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 02 00:00 Backuplogs_202212020000
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 12 00:00 Backuplogs_202212120000
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 13 00:00 Backuplogs_202212130000
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 14 00:00 Backuplogs_202212140000
drwxr-xr-x 3 test test 26 Dec 15 00:00 Backuplogs_202212150000
```

I need to delete all the folders except 1st, 15th and last day of every month by using **ONLY** the folder names given above like below,

Backuplogs_2022**1201**0000

calculate the dates for every month to remove the folders except 1st, 15th and last day

Could someone suggest me a logic for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your path `/var/test/logs`, and Try this for removing for current month:

```
#Return last date of the current month
LAST=$(date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +%d)

#Remove all folders except 01, 15, 31
find . -regextype egrep ! -regex "^./Backuplogs_202301(01|15|${LAST}).*"  -delete
```

If you want it for multiple months then you can add `for-loop` above, based on your range.

Comment: Thank you @Niyaz. I ran for the current month and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I need to run this in loop for the last 7 years. By using for loop like this is not fetching me correct results:   

for ((i=1; i<=12; i++))
do
LAST=$(date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +%d)
find . -regextype egrep ! -regex "^./Backuplogs_2023$i(01|15|${LAST}).*"  -delete
done

Should i change something in the above code to get the loop running for all the 12 months of the year for the past 7 years

Comment: @Megu, If you want to run it for seven years then you need two `for-loop`. First for years, and second for all months of each year. Also, needs lots of customization. But please use `-print` instead of `-delete` until you're sure that your program works.